# Login com Facebook em Aplicação Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk

Boa tarde pessoal, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que requer fazer login com o facebook. Porém existe um detalhe: eu preciso da suporte na aplicação ao sdk android no minino do 3.0 que é o 11, só que a api do facebook mais recente só da suporte a partir do sdk 15 que é o 4.0.3.

Alguém sabe como posso implementar esse login com o facebook dando suporte a versões do android mais antigas?

Desde já agradeço.